# RDLC - An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, reporting, rdlc, localreport

I am getting weird experience with RDLC report. In my live project, I am printing a report in pdf format when user want to print his application form. For a particular user id I am getting exception but for all other users the report is printing and working fine.

The exception is as follows:

> An error occurred during local report processing.    at
> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format,
> Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode
> pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback,
> Warning[]& warnings)    at
> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format,
> Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode
> pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String&
> fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)    at
> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String
> deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String&
> encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]&
> warnings)    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String
> format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String&
> fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)    at
> User_ApplicationForm.print_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> c:\eAwas\User\ApplicationForm.aspx.cs:line 89
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms

I am unable to understand the exception. It also further confuses me when I am trying to print application form with other user's login id, the RDLC report is working fine. Please help in resolving this.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? Did you check for one?